# JProgressBar for operation time consumption operations

Tags: java, swing

I have a method called evaluate() that takes as parameter a File object. This method has to do a heavy and long running job (at least 5 seconds per file). Also this method will be synchonized.

A user, can choose some files using a JFileChooser and for each selected file, evaluate method will be invoked. Because this task takes some time, i want to display a JProgressBar(indeterminate will be set to true) for each file with message "File with name xyz is being processed". If EDT is executing evaluate task, gui will be frozen, so the progress bar will not be properly displayed. Also, I tried with a Swing Worker, but how could know EDT when SwingWorker job is done, and display another progress bar for next file? 
Until now i tried this, but with no result :

```
private void processLabsEvaluation(File[] selectedFiles) {
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
            final File file = selectedFiles[i];
            Frame progressBar = new ProgressBarEvaluation();
            progressBar.setVisible(true);
            SwingWorker<LabResult, Void> worker 
               = new SwingWorker<LabResult, Void>() {

               @Override
               public LabResult doInBackground() {
                 LabResult intDoc = LabEvaluator.getInstance().evaluate(file);
                 return intDoc;
               }
             };
             worker.execute();

            progressBar.setVisible(false);

    }
    }

    private class LoadClicked implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fileChooser.showOpenDialog(LoadLabsPanel.this);
            File[] selectedFiles = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
            if(selectedFiles == null) {
                return;
            }
            processLabsEvaluation(selectedFiles);
        }
     }
```

Comment: You can use one `SwingWorker` to run the whole thing, and use `publish()` for the [interim results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) (each processed file).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) to execute a `Runnable` in the EDT. So after your worker thread has finished evaluating one file, you can create a `Runnable` that updates the progress bar and then pass this runnable to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.